# How to dynamically include/bypass a filter in a video pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

In a gstreamer live video pipeline, I want to include or not a filter, according to the user's command.  I have thought of several ways to do this, but don't know which is best, meaning simplest to code, works real-time, smoothly streaming, reliable, doesn't need monkeying with details of pads or element internals, doesn't risk memory leaks or otherwise inspire someone to cuss at it.

For a simple example, suppose I want to make this pipeline:

```
videotestsrc  -> agingtv -> autovideosink
```

but when the user taps a key change it to/from:

```
videotestsrc  ->  autovideosink
```

The ways I thought of accomplishing this include:

1. Dynamically change the pipeline topology .  There are articles on this, and example code.  Messier than a gstreamer noob such as myself cares to deal with.
2. Keep the filter in all the time. Topology doesn't change. Use a tee and a couple valve elements around the filter, like this:

```
    
    --> tee (src0)-> agingtv -> valve1 --> (sink0)(join branches) -->
            (src1)------>----> valve2 ---> (sink1)
```

3. Then I noticed output-selector and input selector.  Being more of an analog electronics guy, these make sense to me.

```
    
    --> outputselector (src_0)------------------>(sink_0) inputselector --->
                       (src_1)----> agingtv ---->(sink_1)
```

Which would an experienced gstreamer pro choose?  Any of these or something I don't yet know about?

Comment: (ugh, terrible ascii art!)

Comment: you can use a valve element, that would be much simpler for you usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the sample code which changes from following pipeline every second you can add the piece of code to handle your key events:

videotestsrc -> q1 -> agingtv -> videoconvert -> q2-> autovideosink
videotestsrc -> q1 -> identity -> videoconvert -> q2-> autovideosink

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

static gchar *opt_effects = NULL;

#define DEFAULT_EFFECTS "identity,agingtv"

static GstPad *blockpad;
static GstElement *conv_before;
static GstElement *conv_after;
static GstElement *cur_effect;
static GstElement *pipeline;

static GQueue effects = G_QUEUE_INIT;

static GstPadProbeReturn
event_probe_cb (GstPad * pad, GstPadProbeInfo * info, gpointer user_data)
{
  GMainLoop *loop = user_data;
  GstElement *next;

  if (GST_EVENT_TYPE (GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_DATA (info)) != GST_EVENT_EOS)
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_PASS;

  gst_pad_remove_probe (pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_ID (info));

  /* push current effect back into the queue */
  g_queue_push_tail (&effects, gst_object_ref (cur_effect));
  /* take next effect from the queue */
  next = g_queue_pop_head (&effects);
  if (next == NULL) {
    GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (pad, "no more effects");
    g_main_loop_quit (loop);
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP;
  }

  g_print ("Switching from '%s' to '%s'..\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (cur_effect),
      GST_OBJECT_NAME (next));

  gst_element_set_state (cur_effect, GST_STATE_NULL);

  /* remove unlinks automatically */
  GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (pipeline, "removing %" GST_PTR_FORMAT, cur_effect);
  gst_bin_remove (GST_BIN (pipeline), cur_effect);

  GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (pipeline, "adding   %" GST_PTR_FORMAT, next);
  gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (pipeline), next);

  GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (pipeline, "linking..");
  gst_element_link_many (conv_before, next, conv_after, NULL);

  gst_element_set_state (next, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  cur_effect = next;
  GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (pipeline, "done");

  return GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP;
}

static GstPadProbeReturn
pad_probe_cb (GstPad * pad, GstPadProbeInfo * info, gpointer user_data)
{
  GstPad *srcpad, *sinkpad;

  GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (pad, "pad is blocked now");

  /* remove the probe first */
  gst_pad_remove_probe (pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_ID (info));

  /* install new probe for EOS */
  srcpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (cur_effect, "src");
  gst_pad_add_probe (srcpad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK |
      GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_DOWNSTREAM, event_probe_cb, user_data, NULL);
  gst_object_unref (srcpad);

  /* push EOS into the element, the probe will be fired when the
   * EOS leaves the effect and it has thus drained all of its data */
  sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (cur_effect, "sink");
  gst_pad_send_event (sinkpad, gst_event_new_eos ());
  gst_object_unref (sinkpad);

  return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

static gboolean
timeout_cb (gpointer user_data)
{
  gst_pad_add_probe (blockpad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM,
      pad_probe_cb, user_data, NULL);

  return TRUE;
}

static gboolean
bus_cb (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * msg, gpointer user_data)
{
  GMainLoop *loop = user_data;

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:{
      GError *err = NULL;
      gchar *dbg;

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &dbg);
      gst_object_default_error (msg->src, err, dbg);
      g_clear_error (&err);
      g_free (dbg);
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GError *err = NULL;
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstElement *src, *q1, *q2, *effect, *sink;
  gchar **effect_names, **e;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  effect_names = g_strsplit (DEFAULT_EFFECTS, ",", -1);

  for (e = effect_names; e != NULL && *e != NULL; ++e) {
    GstElement *el;

    el = gst_element_factory_make (*e, NULL);
    if (el) {
      g_print ("Adding effect '%s'\n", *e);
      g_queue_push_tail (&effects, el);
    }
  }

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");

  src = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", NULL);
  g_object_set (src, "is-live", TRUE, NULL);

  q1 = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", NULL);

  blockpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (q1, "src");

  conv_before = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", NULL);

  effect = g_queue_pop_head (&effects);
  cur_effect = effect;

  conv_after = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", NULL);

  q2 = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", NULL);

  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", NULL);

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), src, q1, conv_before, effect,
      conv_after, q2, sink, NULL);

  gst_element_link_many (src, q1, conv_before, effect, conv_after,
      q2, sink, NULL);

  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  gst_bus_add_watch (GST_ELEMENT_BUS (pipeline), bus_cb, loop);

  g_timeout_add_seconds (1, timeout_cb, loop);

  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);

  return 0;
}
```

Just a gstreamer pro would do the above to have as minimal elements in pipeline to reduce the CPU usage. Another option would be to have the pipeline as below all the time:

```
videotestsrc -> agingtv -> videoconvert -> autovideosink
```

And when user hits a key press set the following properties of agingtv as below:

```
color-aging=false
dusts=false
pits=false
scratch-lines=0
```

And when you want to switch it back set it as below again:

```
color-aging=true
dusts=true
pits=true
scratch-lines=7 (default is 7)
```